# How can I save a pivot table connected to SSAS model as static worksheet?

Tags: excel, ssas, ssas-tabular

I am working on an Excel report connected to a SSAS model. We need to save the excel spreadsheet as a static Excel file, it means, not connected anymore to the SSAS model.
[image]

I am using Excel 2016. Is there a way to make this Excel report report a static report other then copying the sections you want to another sheet?
e.g. when save the pivot table as xls simply save as a different type to break the relation with  the ssas model?

I am trying using export as well but not working so far. May be someone has a best idea.

Any help should be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the Data tab in the ribbon and click the "Queries and Connections" button in the "Queries and Connections" ribbon group this will open up a side panel on the right showing a list of connections used in the excel file. You can delete connections here to unlink the connection and prevent future refreshes of those  pivot tables.

This screenshot is from the latest version of Excel, but I believe Excel 2016 has all these things in the same location:
[image: screenshot]